# Kafka Consumer Concurrency on Spring Boot Application Startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, concurrency, apache-kafka

I am experimenting on Kafka with Spring Boot.

- Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE
- Spring-Kafka 2.2.0

My KafkaConfig for consumers looks like below:

```
@Bean
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor messageProcessorExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    exec.setCorePoolSize(10);
    exec.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    exec.setKeepAliveSeconds(30);
    exec.setThreadNamePrefix("kafkaConsumer-");
    return exec;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());

    JsonDeserializer<String> valueDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    valueDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("path.to.my.pkgs");
    consumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(valueDeserializer);

    consumerFactory.setKeyDeserializer(new StringDeserializer());

    return consumerFactory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(10);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(4000);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(messageProcessorExecutor());

    return factory;
}

private Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "groupId");
    return props;
}
```

And I have one consumer.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "Topic1", groupId = "groupId")
public void consume(MyMessage message) {
    logger.info("Message is read.);
}
```

As you can see above configs, I have configured concurrency as 10. It is working in a way I want. When I push 3 message into related topic in Kafka, I can see each messages are consumed by different threads.

```
2018-12-12 23:41:50.416  INFO 1937 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.e.kafkalistener.KafkaListeners         : Message is read.
2018-12-12 23:41:50.414  INFO 1937 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.e.kafkalistener.KafkaListeners         : Message is read.
2018-12-12 23:41:50.461  INFO 1937 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.e.kafkalistener.KafkaListeners         : Message is read.
```

However, consumer is working with one thread on application startup.
My test case:

1. shutdown the application
2. send 3 more messages to same Kafka topic
3. start the consumer application

I am seing logs like above:

```
2018-12-12 23:51:51.525  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.e.kafkalistener.KafkaListeners         : Message is read.
2018-12-12 23:51:51.526  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.e.kafkalistener.KafkaListeners         : Message is read.
2018-12-12 23:51:51.526  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.e.kafkalistener.KafkaListeners         : Message is read.
2018-12-12 23:51:54.104  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=groupId] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-12 23:51:54.139  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=groupId] Revoking previously assigned partitions [I have deleted here to make log more readable]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.139  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [I have deleted here to make log more readable]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.139  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=groupId] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-12 23:51:54.155  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-9] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-10, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.155  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.156  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-9] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-10, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-0, Topic1-1, Topic1-2, Topic1-3, Topic1-12, Topic1-13, Topic1-14, Topic1-15, Topic1-16, Topic1-17, Topic1-18, Topic1-19, Topic1-4, Topic1-5, Topic1-6, Topic1-7, Topic1-8, Topic1-9, Topic1-10, Topic1-11]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.156  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-60, Topic1-61, Topic1-62, Topic1-63, Topic1-64, Topic1-65, Topic1-66, Topic1-67, Topic1-76, Topic1-77, Topic1-78, Topic1-79, Topic1-68, Topic1-69, Topic1-70, Topic1-71, Topic1-72, Topic1-73, Topic1-74, Topic1-75]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.156  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.157  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-116, Topic1-117, Topic1-118, Topic1-119, Topic1-108, Topic1-109, Topic1-110, Topic1-111, Topic1-112, Topic1-113, Topic1-114, Topic1-115, Topic1-100, Topic1-101, Topic1-102, Topic1-103, Topic1-104, Topic1-105, Topic1-106, Topic1-107]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.157  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.157  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-156, Topic1-157, Topic1-158, Topic1-159, Topic1-148, Topic1-149, Topic1-150, Topic1-151, Topic1-152, Topic1-153, Topic1-154, Topic1-155, Topic1-140, Topic1-141, Topic1-142, Topic1-143, Topic1-144, Topic1-145, Topic1-146, Topic1-147]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.157  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.158  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-160, Topic1-161, Topic1-162, Topic1-163, Topic1-172, Topic1-173, Topic1-174, Topic1-175, Topic1-176, Topic1-177, Topic1-178, Topic1-179, Topic1-164, Topic1-165, Topic1-166, Topic1-167, Topic1-168, Topic1-169, Topic1-170, Topic1-171]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.158  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.158  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-124, Topic1-125, Topic1-126, Topic1-127, Topic1-128, Topic1-129, Topic1-130, Topic1-131, Topic1-120, Topic1-121, Topic1-122, Topic1-123, Topic1-132, Topic1-133, Topic1-134, Topic1-135, Topic1-136, Topic1-137, Topic1-138, Topic1-139]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.158  INFO 2023 --- [afkaConsumer-10] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.159  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.159  INFO 2023 --- [afkaConsumer-10] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-28, Topic1-29, Topic1-30, Topic1-31, Topic1-32, Topic1-33, Topic1-34, Topic1-35, Topic1-20, Topic1-21, Topic1-22, Topic1-23, Topic1-24, Topic1-25, Topic1-26, Topic1-27, Topic1-36, Topic1-37, Topic1-38, Topic1-39]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.159  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.159  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-188, Topic1-189, Topic1-190, Topic1-191, Topic1-192, Topic1-193, Topic1-194, Topic1-195, Topic1-180, Topic1-181, Topic1-182, Topic1-183, Topic1-184, Topic1-185, Topic1-186, Topic1-187, Topic1-196, Topic1-197, Topic1-198, Topic1-199]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.163  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=groupId] Successfully joined group with generation 41
2018-12-12 23:51:54.165  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-92, Topic1-93, Topic1-94, Topic1-95, Topic1-96, Topic1-97, Topic1-98, Topic1-99, Topic1-84, Topic1-85, Topic1-86, Topic1-87, Topic1-88, Topic1-89, Topic1-90, Topic1-91, Topic1-80, Topic1-81, Topic1-82, Topic1-83]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.189  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=groupId] Setting newly assigned partitions [Topic1-52, Topic1-53, Topic1-54, Topic1-55, Topic1-56, Topic1-57, Topic1-58, Topic1-59, Topic1-44, Topic1-45, Topic1-46, Topic1-47, Topic1-48, Topic1-49, Topic1-50, Topic1-51, Topic1-40, Topic1-41, Topic1-42, Topic1-43]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.192  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-52, Topic1-53, Topic1-54, Topic1-55, Topic1-56, Topic1-57, Topic1-58, Topic1-59, Topic1-44, Topic1-45, Topic1-46, Topic1-47, Topic1-48, Topic1-49, Topic1-50, Topic1-51, Topic1-40, Topic1-41, Topic1-42, Topic1-43]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.278  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-60, Topic1-61, Topic1-62, Topic1-63, Topic1-64, Topic1-65, Topic1-66, Topic1-67, Topic1-76, Topic1-77, Topic1-78, Topic1-79, Topic1-68, Topic1-69, Topic1-70, Topic1-71, Topic1-72, Topic1-73, Topic1-74, Topic1-75]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.278  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-9] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-0, Topic1-1, Topic1-2, Topic1-3, Topic1-12, Topic1-13, Topic1-14, Topic1-15, Topic1-16, Topic1-17, Topic1-18, Topic1-19, Topic1-4, Topic1-5, Topic1-6, Topic1-7, Topic1-8, Topic1-9, Topic1-10, Topic1-11]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.283  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-116, Topic1-117, Topic1-118, Topic1-119, Topic1-108, Topic1-109, Topic1-110, Topic1-111, Topic1-112, Topic1-113, Topic1-114, Topic1-115, Topic1-100, Topic1-101, Topic1-102, Topic1-103, Topic1-104, Topic1-105, Topic1-106, Topic1-107]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.283  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-156, Topic1-157, Topic1-158, Topic1-159, Topic1-148, Topic1-149, Topic1-150, Topic1-151, Topic1-152, Topic1-153, Topic1-154, Topic1-155, Topic1-140, Topic1-141, Topic1-142, Topic1-143, Topic1-144, Topic1-145, Topic1-146, Topic1-147]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.283  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-188, Topic1-189, Topic1-190, Topic1-191, Topic1-192, Topic1-193, Topic1-194, Topic1-195, Topic1-180, Topic1-181, Topic1-182, Topic1-183, Topic1-184, Topic1-185, Topic1-186, Topic1-187, Topic1-196, Topic1-197, Topic1-198, Topic1-199]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.283  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-124, Topic1-125, Topic1-126, Topic1-127, Topic1-128, Topic1-129, Topic1-130, Topic1-131, Topic1-120, Topic1-121, Topic1-122, Topic1-123, Topic1-132, Topic1-133, Topic1-134, Topic1-135, Topic1-136, Topic1-137, Topic1-138, Topic1-139]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.283  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-160, Topic1-161, Topic1-162, Topic1-163, Topic1-172, Topic1-173, Topic1-174, Topic1-175, Topic1-176, Topic1-177, Topic1-178, Topic1-179, Topic1-164, Topic1-165, Topic1-166, Topic1-167, Topic1-168, Topic1-169, Topic1-170, Topic1-171]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.283  INFO 2023 --- [afkaConsumer-10] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-28, Topic1-29, Topic1-30, Topic1-31, Topic1-32, Topic1-33, Topic1-34, Topic1-35, Topic1-20, Topic1-21, Topic1-22, Topic1-23, Topic1-24, Topic1-25, Topic1-26, Topic1-27, Topic1-36, Topic1-37, Topic1-38, Topic1-39]
2018-12-12 23:51:54.283  INFO 2023 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [Topic1-92, Topic1-93, Topic1-94, Topic1-95, Topic1-96, Topic1-97, Topic1-98, Topic1-99, Topic1-84, Topic1-85, Topic1-86, Topic1-87, Topic1-88, Topic1-89, Topic1-90, Topic1-91, Topic1-80, Topic1-81, Topic1-82, Topic1-83]
```

I think, 3 unread messages are being read before all consumers are ready, and each of them is read by consumer named **kafkaConsumer-1**. This situation did not change when I pushed much more messages when the consumer application is closed.

How can I concurrently read every unread messages on application startup ?

Comment: do you know how many partitions do you have? if you only have 1 partition, then only one consumer can be used.

Comment: @dtheo I have 200 partitions. I think, If i had only one partition, I couldnt see concurrent read before restarting the application. Even, I can see concurrent reading after consuming all messages that are sent to kafka when the application is closed. Like I said, on application startup; unread messages are being consumed with one thread, after it is finished, concurrent reading is started.

Comment: When you start your first consumer, it communicates with kafka and consume all partitions, while other threads is still trying to communicate with kafka. Once other consumers manage to communicate with kafka, kafka then will rebalance the partition to each consumers.

Comment: @dtheo I added Thread.sleep(10000L) on my consumer. This time, I am seing that 2 consumers are working now. Working consumer names kafkaConsumer-1 and kafkaConsumer-2. I am also seing that [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=groupId] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing  logs for other consumers.

Comment: how can I be sure to all consumer workers are working before starting to consumption on topic on application startup ?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that, since kafka handles the rebalances. One way would be not let any message to be produced into the topic until all consumers have been assigned one or more partitions. And that is not a good way.